# Call fragment method from dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

I'm trying to call `fragment` function from `dialogfragment`. My application is based on `navigation drawer` which contains container for `fragments`. At one of my `fragments` I make `retrofit` request and I also can open `dialogfragment`  from this `fragment`. But I faced with one very serious problem - I can't get `SharedPreferences` after calling fragment function from `dialogFragment`. Here how I call this method:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
                JobList jobList = new JobList();
                jobList.testFunction();
            }
        });
```

and here is my `testFunction()`:

```
public void testFunction() {
        sp = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
        Log.w("MY_tag", sp.getString("access_token", ""));
    }
```

my testFunction contains only experimental logs, because I try to get data from sharedpreferences but I get only error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

after putting breakpoint I understood that I can't receive any context for getting sharedPreferences. I can't understand how to solve my problem, and I will be happy if smb help me with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try as follows

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
            JobList jobList = new JobList();
            jobList.testFunction(view);
        }
    });

  public void testFunction(View view) {
    sp = Objects.requireNonNull(view.getContext()).getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);
    Log.w("MY_tag", sp.getString("access_token", ""));
}
```

Comment: but as I see it is too hard to call fragment properly from dialogFragment, because I also faced with another different problems with view elements?

Answer (score 1):

Easy and Recommended way:

First make a callback in fragment: How?

```
interface DialogCallBack{
    void callback(View view);
}
```

implement interface on your fragment, and when you create constructor for your dialogfragment, just pass the callback for that fragment.

Then in your dialogFragment:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
            listener.callback(view);
        }
    });
```

listener call interface method which is implemented on fragment. So do this inside your fragment:

```
@override
callback(View view){
 testFunction(view);
}
```